# Which reasons are behind analog synthesizers creating less "perfect" or "defined" waveforms, when compared to their digital counterparts?

Tags: synthesizer

While doing some tests for [this music stack exchange question regarding differences in the waveforms of different synthesizers](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/25159/7218), I noticed that a digital synthesizer sawtooth waveform tends to look something like this:

[image: Sawtooth waveform]

While an analog (or virtual analog) synthesizer waveform tends to look more like this:

[image: Analog sawtooth]

What's the difference between analog and digital oscillators that is inducing this distinction? Why are analog synthesizers implementations of sawtooth (and maybe other waveforms) not so "well defined", when compared to digitally generated sawtooth waveforms?

Comment: How was the analog synthesizer waveform measured? Digital oscilloscope? Was the scope probe compensated? Looks to me like an exponential rise, then sharp falling edge after about 1.5 time constant. There also appears to be ringing / undershoot after the falling edge. I could believe the exponential rise might be due to charging load cap, but the prominent jogs in the falling edge look like a digital sampling system measurement artifact. So it's hard for me to tell from this how much of this is from the measurement system itself vs the device under test.

Comment: Simpler circuits. Replace the charging resistor with a current source and you have either upgraded your analog synth - or destroyed its character!

Comment: Not entirely. That would have been the case in the earliest days when every component was expensive. But now the overriding reason would be the same you need the correct varnish for a violin, or the right tube amp (Vox AC30) for your guitar : that's what gives the sound its character.

Comment: Back in the 80's or 90's when the "early music" movement started recreating the sound of Bach and Vivaldi on period instruments I wondered if one day there would be a craze for restoring vintage Moog synthesisers ... seems that's started happening...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The digital sawtooth waveform is going to "look" nice and linear because they are often generated from a D/A converter where some software steps the D/A inputs in even steps per unit time.

The common analog technique to generate a sawtooth waveform is to use an oscillator circuit that charges a capacitor through a resistance between two voltage thresholds. This type of circuit design invariably will exhibit some exponential curvature of the ramp of the sawtooth waveform. It is totally possible to configure another type of analogue oscillator that changes the capacitor from a constant current source instead of a simple resistor. When a capacitor charges from a constant current source the ramp will be linear like the digitally generated waveform.

There are several possible reasons that the analog designs trend toward the R/C type design as opposed to the constant current source type design:

1. The designer was not well versed in circuit design techniques and
   never explored all the available techniques.
2. Building a constant current source type design takes more components
   and is thus more expensive.
3. And as Andy tried to point out in the comments above, it probably does
   not make a substantial difference in the end result if there is some
   exponential curvature to the ramp or if it is linear.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at a sawtooth waveform of an analogue synthesizer (in the past) and it looked a substantially more precise ramp than shown in the diagram in the question.

Down to the nitty gritty. What makes a square wave or triangle wave or sawtooth wave individually distinctive are the harmonics of the waveform and these harmonics produce a "tone" that creates this individuality.

Following the basic oscillator section in an analogue synthesizer is "filtering" and this filtering can be set to reduce the harmonics (make it sound more like a sinewave) or enhance the harmonics - basically make it a richer sound.

So, if you have a sawtooth waveform that is as shown in the diagram, applying a little more high pass filtering will likely make it sound like a "perfect" sawtooth. It has to be remembered that the main distinctive sound comes from the relatively much faster fall-time rather than the linear or semi-exponential rise time.

Comment: @JCPedroza It was years ago but the circuits used an analogue integrator gated with a square wave (from memory). Why don't you do a Fourier analysis - you'll pretty much realize that the main harmonic content comes from the fast fall-time.

Comment: Different circuits have less than ideal linear characteristics BUT like I've said a couple of times now, the distinctive sound of a sawtooth comes from the fast fall-time (or rise time if inverted). Slightly less than "near=perfect" fall times will have a much more distinctive effect than the ramp shape and I'm not going to speculate on what circuits make those fast edges different.